# getting error while calling getrandomnumber in my smart contract

Tags: solidity, gas-estimate, remix-tests

error message: Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?

```
execution reverted { "originalError": { "code": 3, "data": "0x8129bbcd", "message": "execution reverted" } }
```

[image: this is my code for smart contract]

I've done all the necessary things such as sending LINK to my smart contract, deploying my contract.
Please let me know what wrong am I doing and how to make it right.

Comment: Not an answer but consider using [custom errors](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/04/21/custom-errors/) instead of revert reason strings. Compared to revert reason strings, custom errors are easier to work with, more gas efficient, and more elegant.

Comment: could you please show me where and how to implement the custom errors ?

Comment: Check the blog post I linked in my previous comment.

Comment: Please paste your code instead of a screenshot

Comment: did you find the solution. I am having same exact error